# Access value from a JavaScript map only possible from DevTools

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, maps

So I'm trying to access values in an array returned from a third=party service (Twilio) and I can get exactly what I need when I place

```
room.participants.forEach(function(participant){
    console.log(Array.from(participant.tracks));
});
```

In Dev Tools, I receive:

```
(2) [Array(2), Array(2)]
0: (2) ["f469c8e5-4f94-4752-b018-af02d32fe448", AudioTrack]
1: (2) ["be6c2aa6-4c7c-4431-a964-a711f000562a", VideoTrack]
length :2
__proto__ : Array(0)
```

But the same code in my script produces `[]` as a result. This isn't an issue of timing, because I am able to console.log both room.participants as well as the map of the individual tracks by using

```
var myKeys = room.participants.keys();
console.log(myKeys); 
var myParticipant = room.participants.get(myKeys.next().value);
console.log(myParticipant);
console.log(myParticipant.audioTracks);
console.log(myParticipant.videoTracks);
```

But as soon as I attempt to access the values of the tracks through the same methods `foo.next().value` I receive an empty map and if I try the `Array.from()` method I receive an empty array.
What is going on?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log()` will give you a real-time view of the object you're logging, so if it is a timing issue, then by the time you look at the console, the objects you're logging will have been updated.

So the solution in that case would lie in how exactly the data is being populated.

Comment: But when I log out myParticipant in my code, I can see the the .tracks map which has the data I need. Why can't I call Array.from(myParticipant.tracks.values) and receive something other than an empty array?

Comment: The log of myParticipant looks like `tracks : Map(2) {"f469c8e5-4f94-4752-b018-af02d32fe448" => AudioTrack, "be6c2aa6-4c7c-4431-a964-a711f000562a" => VideoTrack}` <br>logging (in my code) myParticipant.tracks looks like `Map(0) {}
size:(...)
__proto__:Map[[Entries]]:Array(2)
0:{"f469c8e5-4f94-4752-b018-af02d32fe448" => AudioTrack}
1:{"be6c2aa6-4c7c-4431-a964-a711f000562a" => VideoTrack}
length:2`

Comment: You say it's not a matter of timing, but then you say that if you log `room.participants` in the dev tools, you get the data. Well aren't you doing the logging *after* your code has had a chance to run? If so, then why do you insist that it isn't timing related?

Comment: Because I'm silly. It turns out that if I called it later, it would work. I don't understand why I can "see" the values I need from the logs produced by the script but not access them until later, but that's the case. I've accepted your answer, thanks!